# Cells of umbilical cord - mom's or son's?

Tags: human-biology, reproduction

Let's say we have a mother giving a birth to a son. In a very clear manner the cells of these two individuals are very different, of course. Yet there is an umbilical cord connecting them. Then there should be a clearly defined "border" somewhere on its way where the mother's cells meet the cells of her son, is that so? How is it even possible?! ;)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Cells of umbilical cord - mom's or son's?

Answer: Son's.

The interface you are looking for is in the placenta. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placenta

Formally the fetal side of the placenta is called the Chorion frondosum, which develops from the outer cells of blastocyst (trophoblast), and the maternal side of the placenta, Decidua basalis, which develops from the maternal uterine tissue.

> How is it even possible?

Immune tolerance in pregnancy or gestational/maternal immune tolerance

The placenta functions as an immunological barrier between the mother and the fetus, creating an immunologically privileged site. For this purpose, it uses several mechanisms

1. It secretes Neurokinin B containing phosphocholine molecules. This
   is the same mechanism used by parasitic nematodes to avoid detection
   by the immune system of their host.
2. Also, there is the presence of small lymphocytic suppressor cells in the
   fetus that inhibit maternal cytotoxic T cells by inhibiting the
   response to interleukin 2.
3. The placental trophoblast cells do not express the classical MHC
   class I isotypes HLA-A and HLA-B, unlike most other cells in the
   body, and this absence is assumed to prevent destruction by maternal
   cytotoxic T cells, which otherwise would recognize the fetal HLA-A
   and HLA-B molecules as foreign. On the other hand, they do express
   the atypical MHC class I isotypes HLA-E and HLA-G, which is assumed
   to prevent destruction by maternal NK cells, which otherwise destroy
   cells that do not express any MHC class I. However, trophoblast
   cells do express the rather typical HLA-C.
4. It forms a syncytium without any extracellular spaces between cells
   in order to limit the exchange of migratory immune cells between the
   developing embryo and the body of the mother (something an
   epithelium will not do sufficiently, as certain blood cells are
   specialized to be able to insert themselves between adjacent
   epithelial cells). The fusion of the cells is apparently caused by
   viral fusion proteins from endosymbiotic endogenous retrovirus
   (ERV). An immunoevasive action was the initial normal behavior of
   the viral protein, in order to avail for the virus to spread to
   other cells by simply merging them with the infected one. It is
   believed that the ancestors of modern viviparous mammals evolved
   after an infection by this virus, enabling the fetus to better
   resist the immune system of the mother.

Other mechanisms include exposure to immune modulating factors present in seminal fluid from vaginal and oral sex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-eclampsia#paternal_tolerance

Comment: just to add the placenta evolved from the yolk of the ancestral eggs, It makes it a bit easier to see how the structure could evolve.